# How to pass Each database table row into relavent jLabels in Java mysql

Tags: java

i am  create a simple rating system. i have only 3 question the database table. i attached screen shot image below.

[image]

those question  are
a
b
c
what i need is i have put 3 jLabels in JFrame i need to fetch the from database table and pass in to relavent
Jlables i attached the screen shot below.

[image]

but result only displayed c only means last row data only displayed. i need to display question 1 - a,
question 2 - b,question 3 - c . how to do it what i tried so far i attached below.

```
public void question()
    {
    
      String query = "select * from rate";
      Statement stat =null;
      ResultSet rs;
     
          try {
            stat = con.createStatement();
             rs = stat.executeQuery(query);
              
              while(rs.next())
              {
                  lblq1.setText(rs.getString(2));
                  lblq2.setText(rs.getString(2));
                  lblq3.setText(rs.getString(2));
              }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         
    }
```

Comment: each time you do rs.next() you get one row out of the result. so you are just putting the same value in each field. iterate over the next(), and set a value for a different field each time

Comment: have to write three while loop to do the task.

Comment: if(rs.next())
           {
            lblq2.setText(rs.getString(2));
           
           }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
          while(rs.next())
          {
              lblq1.setText(rs.getString(2));
              lblq2.setText(rs.getString(2));
              lblq3.setText(rs.getString(2));
          }
```

into something like this:

```
          int id = 1; 
          while(rs.next())
          {
              if ( id == 1 ) lblq1.setText(rs.getString(2));
              if ( id == 2 ) lblq2.setText(rs.getString(2));
              if ( id == 3 ) lblq3.setText(rs.getString(2));
              id += 1;
          }
```

In your current code, you set the text for all three feelds for every value, and you end up with all of them containing the last value.
You need to check which value you want to set in which field.
There are better (more efficient) ways to write this code (switch / if else if ) but for an example, this should be sufficient.